# How do I sort objects by a certain field (like _.sortBy) in plain JS?

Tags: javascript, sorting, momentjs, lodash

I am trying to sort the array based on one property `start` of the array objects.

```
events = _.sortBy(events, function(a) {
    return moment(new Date(a.start)).format();
});
```

This gives me the correct results. However, the following does not.

```
events = events.sort(function(a, b) {
    return moment(new Date(a.start)).format() > moment(new Date(b.start)).format();
});
```

Does anyone know what is happening?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q24zx11h/1/

Comment: The `sort` function argument should return one of `{-1; 0; 1}` not boolean. Btw, is there a reason you wrap date objects in a `moment` object?

Comment: You don't need to do `foo = foo.sort(..)`, `.sort` has side effects/modifies the original array

Comment: I just want to compare the time that's all. I do `moment(new Date(xxx))` instead of just `moment(xxx)` because latter gives me warning messages sometimes. maybe what I do is not necessary?

Comment: ok I realized maybe I shouldn't compare strings. easier to do `(new Date(b)).getTime()` comparisons. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparator functions usually return an integer argument indicating the following values:

- -1: a is smaller than b
- 0: a equals b
- 1: a is larger than b

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

A handy trick is to subtract the discrete value of `a` from the discrete value of `b`, in your case for example by using the timestamp:

```
function (a, b) { return (new Date(b)).getTime() - (new Date(a)).getTime(); }
```

If b is now larger than a, it will return a positive value, and so forth.

Comment: @Shih-MinLee Please accept the answer if it answered your question :)

Comment: I'll go with lodash but this should be correct when not using external libraries.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Compare function must return -1, 0 or 1:

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
}
```

Currently your code returns boolean and I think it's parsed to 0 or 1 so your code runs but not correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [the docs of `Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) say:

> `arr.sort([compareFunction])`
>
> If compareFunction is supplied, the array elements are sorted
>   according to the return value of the compare function. If a and b are
>   two elements being compared, then:
>
> - If compareFunction(a, b) is less than 0, sort a to a lower index than b, i.e. a comes first.
> - If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different
>     elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this
>     behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating
>     back to at least 2003) respect this.
> - If compareFunction(a, b) is greater than 0, sort b to a lower index than a.
> - compareFunction(a, b) must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If
>     inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined

Your function returns a boolean, which is then cast to a `Number`, which is `0` or `1`, and in this case `0` means equal (as "these elements are the same, put them in whatever order").

Answer (score 0):

I found same results with both your codes

```
    var manualSort = days.sort(function(a, b) {
        return moment(new Date(a.start)).format() > moment(new Date(b.start)).format();
    });

    var underScoreSort = _.sortBy(days, function(a) {
        return moment(new Date(a.start)).format();
    });
```

Both the arrays returned same results.

Comment: I think it shouldn't. the first result is messed up.

Comment: I tried it having only 2 objects in the days array. It showed same results.